cannot fill curses window region with text - is this the design?
Here is code to simply fill a terminal screen:
import curses

def main(stdscr):
    max_y = curses.LINES
    max_x = curses.COLS
    rows = max_y - 1
    cols = max_x - 3
    
    total_chars1 = rows * cols
    
    stdscr.addstr(f'Screen: {max_y}x{max_x} = {max_x * max_y} chars, Window1: {rows}x{cols} = {rows * cols}, Window2: {rows}')
    stdscr.refresh()
    
    win_start_y = 1
    win_start_x = 0
    
    textwin = curses.newwin(rows, cols, win_start_y, win_start_x)
    pagewin = curses.newwin(rows, 1, 1, max_x - 1)
    
    textwin.addstr('x' * (total_chars1 - 1))
    textwin.refresh()
    pagewin.addstr('y' * (rows - 1))
    pagewin.refresh()
    stdscr.getch()

curses.wrapper(main)

But I find that I can't add the conceived total number of chars. I find that I have to minus by one.

Is this by design? Or something more going on here than what meets the eye?
